# Usefulness of preprocessor directives

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I was looking into some advanced topics in C and stumbled on the `##` operator, and the example given was something like this.

```
#define GLUE_HELPER(x, y) x##y
#define GLUE(x, y) GLUE_HELPER(x, y)
#define AVERAGE(x) \
(((GLUE(Max,x)) - (GLUE(Min,x))) / (GLUE(x,Count)))
```

I am still pretty new to C programming, so when I see macros like these they look almost "magical". Do macros generally get more complex than this? Or are they usually 1-2 line(s) of code?

I was wondering how common these are in production level code bases? I've seen them used in some smaller projects after doing a little research, but was wondering if anyone else has had any experience using them more extensively.

Comment: checkout https://www.boost.org/ and you'll see extremely complex C macros

Comment: [I did the first week of last years advent of code in the preprocessor](https://github.com/camel-cdr/boline/tree/main/aoc22),  if you are interested in more complex usages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do macros generally get more complex than this? Or are they usually 1-2 line(s) of code?

Macros certainly *can* get more complicated than that, and sometimes they do.  It's not clear to me how common is the use of the `##` operator, however. Object-like macros are rarely longer than a line or two, but function-like macros (those that take arguments) are frequently longer.

> I was wondering how common these are in production level code bases?

Very difficult to say.  Details of macro usage are a matter of project history, convention, and style principles.  And opinions about macros and appropriate uses for them have shifted over time.  No one can really study the corpus of all C code everywhere.

I would be inclined to guess, however, that complicated macros are more likely to appear in larger code bases and in older ones.  In larger code bases because more complicated macros are more likely to be (perceived) useful in more complicated code.  In older code bases both because a longer history provides more time for complicated macros to be introduced, and because newer code is comparatively more likely to use *bona fide* functions, instead.

> [I] was wondering if anyone else has had any experience using them more extensively

Sure, lots of people do.  But the conventional wisdom these days is that you should usually prefer a function to a function-like macro.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I'm going to start looking through some _legacy_ code bases on Github or Gitlab just to see what I can find! C is a really cool language and I want to dedicate more time to understanding it more deeply! If you have an suggestions on projects, books, etc. you think might be helpful let me know!